# Use multiple XML Configuration file for same package in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have a situation where I need use multiple XML config file to execute the same package to pass different database and server credentials. So the question is, is there any way for a SSIS package to use more than one config file? If so, how can it be achieved?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the /ConfigFile option of the dtexec.exe utility to specify a a XML configuration file at run time. NOTE THAT you cannot use the /ConfigFile option to replace configured values that you also specified at design time.

See the DTExec documentation here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx

And the SSIS package configuration documentation here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682(v=sql.105).aspx